# Generic Anonymous Inner Class Instantiation

Tags: java, generics

I'm reading up on [WebSocket Endpoints](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/websocket003.htm) in Java EE and I came accross this

```
public class EchoEndpoint extends Endpoint {
   @Override
   public void onOpen(final Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
      session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onMessage(String msg) {
            try {
               session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
            } catch (IOException e) { ... }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

This part,

```
new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {....
```

Is `Whole` a generic Inner class? And since we are specifying String as a type parameter, `onMessage` accepts Strings? This looks really weird to me, we could just subclass `Whole`, and Override `onMessage` and that would be a different class. Then we could pass that with the type parameter to `addMessageHandler` right? But here, we are just overriding it and specifying the type parameter at the same time here right?

EDIT

So I have learned MessageHandler is an interface with two nested interfaces in it

`MessageHandler.Whole<T>` and
`MessageHandler.Partial<T>`

Now we pass an object of the type `MessageHandler` into the method `addMessageHandler`, how could it know that this object implements the `onMessage` method. It's not supposed to know, because this method is in the nested interface `Whole`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Whole a generic Inner class?

No. It's a generic nested class (interface, to be precise), as [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/MessageHandler.html) shows. The term "inner" is for non-static nested classes, which implicitly have a reference to an instance of their owning class. See [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

> And since we are specifying String as a type parameter, onMessage accepts Strings?

Correct, as [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/MessageHandler.Whole.html#onMessage-T-) shows.

> we could just subclass Whole, and Override onMessage and that would be a different class

That's exactly what this code is doing. It creates and instantiates an *anonymous* subclass os Whole.

> Now we pass an object of the type MessageHandler into the method addMessageHandler, how could it know that this object implements the onMessage method. It's not supposed to know, because this method is in the nested interface Whole.

As the [javadoc shows](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/MessageHandler.Whole.html), the interface `Whole` extands the interface `MessageHandler`. That's why you can pass a Whole to a method which expects a MessageHandler (just like you could pass a Banana to a method expecting a Fruit, because Banana is a Fruit).